How can I output records from different tables in one database query?
I use Typeorm
I need to get the records out of the tables. The first table is for the community that the user is subscribed to and the second table is for the user records that the current user is subscribed to
It turns out that the inner strings conflict with each other
    const posts = await db.query(`
      select
      p.*
      from post p
      left join "subsite" s on p.subsite_slug = s.slug
      inner join "subsite_follow" f on f.subsite_id = s.id and f.user_id = $1
      left join "user" u on p.author_id = u.id
      inner join "user_following" uf on uf.user_id_2 = u.id and uf.user_id_1 = $1
    `, [req.user.id])

there are two columns in the user_following table
user_id_1 and user_id_2

Never use a * in your SQL code, you don't have a clue what you're actually selecting. Replace p.* with all the column names you want to select. The mix of LEFT and INNER join is most likely not working, but that's something you should check, you know your data better than anyone else. Ps. p.* means you're only selecting all (unknown) columns from table alias p.

The keyword to search for is "join".

Please see [mre]. The table DDL (including constraints and indexes), sample data, and expected output are required if others are to understand the question. There is insufficient information to ascertain the expected output or to know what is meant by "the inner strings conflict."
